# Fire Event from a C# library into a VB Winform program

Tags: c#, vb.net, visual-studio-2015

I am a C# programmer and have made a C# library for handling a tcp/ip chat.
Now I have the necessity to use it from a Server VB Winform program.
I am pretty sure that this is an easy solution problem but I have been struggling for days.
So in the C# I have that class:

```
public class AsynchronousServer
{
    public AsynchronousServer()
    {
    }

    public delegate void ChangedEventHandler(string strMessage);
    public static event ChangedEventHandler OnNotification;
    public static event ChangedEventHandler OnAnswerReceived;
    ...
}
```

Now I have to focus on the server program:
if that VB program would have been in C# I would have written the code below for connecting the server on a button click

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnStart_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        AsynchronousServer.OnNotification += AsynchronousServer_OnNotification;
        AsynchronousServer.OnAnswerReceived += AsynchronousServer_OnAnswerReceived;
        AsynchronousServer.StartServer(tbxIpAddress.Text,tbxPort.Text);
    }
```

The same program in VB:

```
Imports SocketLibrary

    Public Class Form1
    Private Sub btnStart_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
        AsynchronousServer.OnNotification                       <--- member not present
        AsynchronousServer.OnAnswerReceived                     <--- member not present
        AsynchronousServer.StartServer(tbxIpAddress.Text, tbxPort.Text);<-----OK
    End Sub
End Class
```

the problem is that the member AsynchronousServer.OnNotification is not present at all so I can't add the event.
I am aware that I might have to add the WithEvents keyword but try as I might I couldn't succed.

In short I have to connect that VB winform program to a C# library event which I can't see from my VB class.

Thanks for any help

Patrick

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming you never used VB thus will answer you:
You need to use `AddHandler`:

```
AddHandler AsynchronousServer.OnNotification, AddressOf YourMethod
```

BTW, static events are pretty bad IMHO.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with static events as long as you remember to remove the event handler when you're done. :)

Comment: A pretty good reason to avoid them in my opinion, but yeah its just that.

Answer (score 2):

Visual Basic has [`AddHandler`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/addhandler-statement) and `RemoveHandler` which are roughly equivalent to `C#`s `+=` and `-=` when the item to the left is an `event`.

However, you also have the option to declare some fields (so, more relevant for instance events on class instances) as [`WithEvents`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/modifiers/withevents)<sup>1</sup>. Whenever you assign a reference to a `WithEvents` field, it will automagically remove previous event handlers it installed on the old instance and then install new handlers on the new instance. This works in concert with the [`Handles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/handles-clause) clause which indicates which event handling methods should be hooked up. This lets you take a more "declarative" approach to your event handling. But it will not work with `static` events.

(Note, also, that of course it's generally easy to consume up C# events from VB code - since `WinForms`, etc, were implemented in C# but usable from both languages)

---

<sup>1</sup>I mention this here not because I necessarily recommend it but because you will encounter a fair bit of VB.NET code that uses this form, including form-designer generated code. And in pre-.NET VB, it was *the* way of wiring up event handlers.